# Convert date from some timezone to another one JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I use timezone.js library to convert date from some timezone to current one. There is the following code:

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(date, timezone);
dt.setTimezone("");
console.log(dt);
```

For example, original date is "2013-10-23 11:56:29", timezone is "Europe/Moscow". But I must set a timezone of a current user for conversion. How can I get a name of a current user's timezone? Or give me some alternative way to convert date from original timezone for current one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `getTimezoneOffset()` method, which returns the difference in minutes between UTC time and the user's local time.

(It is generally a best practice to store `DateTime`s in your database as UTC anyway).

```
var now = new Date()
var offsetMinutes = now.getTimezoneOffset();
alert(offsetMinutes);
```

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z72bY/).

To my knowledge, you can't get the name of the time zone from JavaScript, but you could build a dictionary from the [this info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).